# Comparar dos arrays en Laravel, para eliminar o bien añadir

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quiero comparar dos arrays uno el que tengo en la base de datos y otro que traigo a guardar un producto, pero es la primera vez que me encuentro con esto y no se como abordarlo.

**Tengo la siguiente tabla**

| id | oferta_menu_id | categoria_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 2 | 16 | 3 |
| 2 | 16 | 4 |

Entonces cuando guardo un registro compruebo si en su tabla realacionada existe:

```
$comprobarMenu = Oferta_Menu_Categorias::where('oferta_menu_id', $request->menu_id)->first();
```

Entonces yo lo que estoy haciendo ahora si existe, es:

```
$deleteCategorias = Oferta_Menu_Categorias::where('oferta_menu_id', $request->menu_id);
$deleteCategorias->delete();
```

Pero lo que quiero es, que cuando voy a guardar un registro es comparar cuales `ids` si existen o no, para o bien eliminar o añadir.

Por ejemplo si guardo un producto recibo esto en el controlador:

```
"categorias" => array:3 [
        0 => "1"
        1 => "3"
        2 => "4"
      ]
```

En ese caso por ejemplo no deberia de hacer nada, pero si.. :

```
"categorias" => array:5 [
        0 => "1"
        1 => "3"
        2 => "4"
        3 => "5"
        4 => "6"
      ]
```

Si el caso fuese este, deberia de añadir el 5 y el 6 y el resto no tocarlos, pero tambien cabe la posibilidad de que se quite uno:

```
"categorias" => array:4 [
        0 => "1"
        1 => "3" //El cuatro no está hay que eliminarlo
        2 => "5"
        3 => "6"
      ]
```

Cuando lo guardo en la base de datos lo hago así:

```
foreach($request->categorias as $item){
     $addOfertaMenu_Categoria = new Oferta_Menu_Categorias;
     $addOfertaMenu_Categoria->oferta_menu_id = $request->menu_id;
     $addOfertaMenu_Categoria->categoria_id = $item;
     $addOfertaMenu_Categoria->estado = 1;
    
     $addOfertaMenu_Categoria->save();
}
```

Pero como comparo, no se como hacer. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno espero poderte ayudar, yo me enfrente a ese caso hace un tiempo y lo resolví de la siguiente manera. OJO puede haber mejores y puede que haya código innecesario pero a como te expreso a mi me funcionó.

```
PRIMERO EXTRAES LOS DATOS ACTUALES DE LA BD EN ARRAY
$opciones_actuales=encuesta_opciones_model::where('encuesta_id',$encuesta->id)->get()->pluck('id')->toArray();    

ESTAS SON LOS IDS QUE VIENEN EN TU REQUEST
$opciones=$request->get('opcion');
    
CON EL METODO ARRAY DIFF Compara array1 con uno o más arrays y devuelve los valores de array1 que no estén presentes en ninguno de los otros arrays, de esta forma podras saber cuales fueron las opciones eliminadas
if($opciones)
$opciones_eliminadas=array_diff($opciones_actuales,$opciones);



LUEGO RECCORES LOS ELIMINADOS Y LOS BORRAS DE TU BD
 if($opciones_eliminadas)
            {
                $aux=array();
                foreach ($opciones_eliminadas as $ind=> $op)
                    array_push($aux,$ind);
                foreach ($aux as $eliminados)
                {
                    encuesta_opciones_model::where('encuesta_id', implode(\Hashids::decode($id)))->where('id', $eliminados)->delete();
                }
            }

RECORRES LOS IDS QUE VIENEN TU REQUEST Y VERIFICAS, SI EXISTE LO ACTUALIZAS, SI NO LO CREAS
if($opciones)
            foreach ($opciones as $ind=> $opc)
            {
                if(encuesta_opciones_model::where('id',$ind)->exists())
                {
                    $opcion=encuesta_opciones_model::where('id',$ind)->first();
                    $opcion->opcion=$opciones[$ind];
                    $opcion->color=$colores[$ind];
                    $opcion->save();

                }
                else
                {
                    $opcion=new encuesta_opciones_model();
                    $opcion->encuesta_id=implode(\Hashids::decode($id));
                    $opcion->opcion=$opciones[$ind];
                    $opcion->color=$colores[$ind];
                    $opcion->save();
                }
            }
```

ESPERO QUE TE SEA DE AYUDA!!!

Comment: Gracias @HeynerMartinez en cuanto pueda me pongo con ello y te comento

Comment: Hola @HeynerMartinez perdona por tardar en responder pero hasta hoy no me he podido poner. Funciono de forma perfecta! Gracias!!